# one RPI's capability to multi-task with complex Image Processing

Tags: raspicam, opencv, image, cars

I, as part of a project, have decided to implement a small scale version of automated collision avoidance system. I chose to go with Image based object detection. After initial research, I figured out that Arduino can't handle IP (alone), so RPI was the way to go. Having fixed this, I stumbled upon OpenCV. Now my plan of action is something like this.

I plan to buy a 2 wheel drive motor car (link given at the end) and use it as the building block. Use the RPI for *controlling the vehicle as well as for Image Processing* (along with the RPI Camera Accessory) to have a real time operation.For an object, I hope to put a black colour thing in the car's path and then hope to program it to "start" taking action when at a distance of 50 cm, with beeps/LED flash and then eventually brake the motors, bringing the car to a stop. My end goal would be to stop the car somewhere around 10 cm to 15 cm from the object.

I have been reading up on this and figured that RPI with OpenCV should do the job, however being not so experienced with IP and RPI, I am not sure if a simple Black object detection is "easy" for a RPI or not or how complex it is. Based on the first answer given, I am assuming that one RPI should do both the jobs - controlling the car and IP. My question is that Can this system (one RPI) deal/handle with a general object detection - something not black - any shape or colour? OR other way round - Given one RPI and the car, what Type of images can I use for IP, considering its capability? I am guessing Black object would help keep things simple, however not sure. Need advice. (No Machine learning algos are to be employed).

This question is preventing me from going full-throttle. I would genuinely appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Link for the Car Chassis - https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B072ZWRM2B/ref=s9u_simh_gw_i1?ie=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B072ZWRM2B&pd_rd_r=4b652f7f-eb46-11e7-ad04-0b97a8a2142a&pd_rd_w=EJbrw&pd_rd_wg=Bnw5r&pf_rd_m=A3JWKAKR8XB7XF&pf_rd_s=&pf_rd_r=EQ2MK485GXAZKDYYYG1N&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=c210947d-c955-4398-98aa-d1dc27e614f1&pf_rd_i=desktop

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

The Pi is more than capable of handling this task.  There is no need for a separate Arduino.

You will need a motor driver board to drive the motors (assuming you plan to use ordinary DC motors or stepper motors).

I have no knowledge of LabView.

This site prefers not to answer multiple questions in one question.

Comment: thanks for the answer. You atleast clarified something. Could you also shed some light about the type of object that I could detect considering RPI. Also, I was thinking of buying a 2 Wheel drive Chassis directly, I guess that should work (without the motor board you mentioned)? And I did think of making 4 separate questions however but I would have to explain everything everytime, that’s why asked. Hope it isn’t that bad, my first time on this site :P